# Linq Count, question

Tags: c#, linq

I have this simple query ->

```
var games =
from p in _oListGames
where p.Visitor == team.ID
select p
```

I would like to order this select with the COUNT of total games that the p.Visitor has from that list(_oListGames)

How would I do that?

I would like to order the var "games" by the numbers of visitor games they have currently.

Comment: I think you're missing an identifier definition; is team.ID one team or many? Is this an internal query to a larger one? If team.ID is one team, then the count will be equal to the number of elements in the list since ALL games returned will have them as the visiting team. if "team" is another table or collection, it should probably be joined to the game table, and from there Mark's answer should work.

Comment: You are right, it should be p.Visitor, not Team.ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean order by number of visitor games that each game's home team had:

```
var games =
from p in _oListGames
where p.Visitor == team.ID
orderby _oListGames.Count(g => p.Home == g.Visitor) 
select p;
```

Comment: I receive this error : " Cannot implicitly conver type long to bool."

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: OK, I think I understand what you're going for now. Here's one option that I think might work:

```
var gameCounts = _oListGames
    .Where(p => p.Visitor == team.ID)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Home)
    .Select(g => new { Opponent = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```

This is basically like [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663686/linq-count-question/3663717#3663717) but it actually gives you the counts in the results (instead of just ordering by count).

Comment: Not my downvote, but I read it differently, he wants to order it by the count, there are multiple results in the list.  E.g. the team that played the visit 20 times comes before the one that played then 10 times, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var games = from p in _oListGames where p.Visitor == team.ID select p;
int count = games.Count();
```

or you can do this.

```
int count = _oListGames.Count(p=>p.Visitor == team.ID);
```

to sort it by count of team.ID

```
var sortGames = games.OrderBy(s => s.Visitor.Count());
```